# How can i find all the path that less than a maximum in Neo4j DB?

Tags: neo4j

Everyone. I am a new one to use **`Neo4j`** DataBase.

Now, I have a graph which contains nodes and relationships, I want to get **all the path that from A to other nodes which the total cost is less than a maximum**.

The maximum should be changed.
I use **Java** to query **`Neo4j`**. I know `Evaluator` cl ones can depend when we stop traversal the path. But i can give my `Maximum` to The interface `evaluate()`

My code is here:

```
public class MyEvaluators implements Evaluator {

@Override
public Evaluation evaluate(Path path) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Iterable<Relationship> rels = path.relationships();
    double totalCost = 0.0;
    for(Relationship rel: rels){
        totalCost += (double) rel.getProperty("cost");
    }

    return totalCost > MAXIMUM ? Evaluation.EXCLUDE_AND_PRUNE:Evaluation.INCLUDE_AND_CONTINUE;
}}
```

And I don't want to limit the path depth.
So how can I do this query quickly?

Answer (score 0):

Which version are you looking at?

https://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/current/tutorial-traversal/

In the current API you can pass a context object (branch-state) to the traversal, that keeps your current state per branch. So you can accumulate the total cost in the PathEvaluator:

https://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/3.4/javadocs/org/neo4j/graphdb/traversal/PathEvaluator.html

Also perhaps you want to derive from the Dijkstra Evaluator.

https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/blob/3.5/community/graph-algo/src/main/java/org/neo4j/graphalgo/impl/path/Dijkstra.java

Comment: Thank you for your advise first.

I think maybe i was not clearly explain my problem:
like draw a circle, i just know the center, and the radius. I want get then other node in this circle. So i just to find all the  path which total relationship cost less than the radius. 

Now what i meet is that:
1.  the `traversal` interface don't the parameter to input the radius 
2.  I just know the start node and the radius but not have the end node.

I have to write a DFS algorithm by myself just for find all the path.